# Spring Web Socket Java Client

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

How to Write a Java based Spring Web Socket (STOMP) Client. As in Spring we have only javascript based client is provided using stompJS but if we need a java client how should we need to achive it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Spring 4.1 introduces a [SockJs Java Client](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#websocket-fallback-sockjs-client) which is quite useful for server to server communication and performance testing. It doesn't come with a Stomp client (this is certainly in the roadmap) but you can check out the [tests in the sample app](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/portfolio/web/load/StompWebSocketLoadTestClient.java) which has already an implementation. Seems this is what you are looking for.

**Update 8 Sep 2015:**

Spring 4.2 has a STOMP Java client which can be used along with the SockJS Java client. More: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#websocket-stomp-client

Comment: I get `cannot be resolved to a type` for all. I have added all the jars. I have copied all the jars form the  Gradle local repo. I have searched for existance of those class in all jars but I did not get them. I fell all the class are renamed and packages are changed. This URL http://snag.gy/Y9QCy.jpg is the screenshot of what I coded. And I did't get any Idea form the code in git repo. Please can you provide me a sample code.

Comment: seems you are not using Spring 4.1, please check the version is 4.1.0.RELEASE. The packages where these classes are is: org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client

Comment: No No. I have used [spring web socket example](http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) it is latest spring that which Gradle is downloading. In aim of leaving it as server and I created a separate project as client and  in which I have those code you suggested and I added all jars from that example projects into this client project.

Comment: this shows you are using Spring 4.0.7 as you are relying on Spring Boot 1.1.6, override the spring version to use 4.1.0.RELEASE

Comment: Hey now I use 4.1 version and all the compilation error gone except for `StandardWebSocketClient()` and `MyWebSocketHandler()`. Also tell how to exactly replace the index.html (a js client) from the tutorial to this java client.

Comment: Thank you! It's helpful for me.

Comment: How to send message from client to server ?

Answer (score 0):

I would look for websocket clients in Java and build off of those. It seems that Jetty has [a websocket client api](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-client-api.html) as does [too tall nate](http://java-websocket.org/).

Comment: Normal web socket will not have subscribe option.